# Why does focusing on an input field of a jqGrid editable row cause the row to be 'de-selected'?

Tags: jqgrid

I've a jqGrid instance which featured with multiselection and inline editing. I wrote some code in the `beforeSelectRow` event so that the multiple selection can be achieved by ctrl-key, and range selection by shift-key; as well as single selection by without pressing any hotkey. In order to enable the inline editing, I'll call `editRow` when the row is selected twice. However, I get into two strange problems that:

1. Clicking on the input element of any field of the editable row, will make the row be 'de-selected'
2. After re-selecting another row to get into the edit mode, the previous selected row can't be restored even the `restoreRow` is called on the target row properly.

--EDITED--

Select a row

[image: Select a row]

Select a row again to get into edit mode

[image: Select a row again to get into edit mode]

Focus the input box, will 'de-select' the row

[image: Focus the input box, will 'de-select' the row]

Select & edit another row, the previous row can't be restored.

[image: Select another row, the previous row can't be restored.]

-- CODE --

```
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var url_for_save_edit = this.p.editurl;
        var last_selected_row = this.p.selrow;
        var cur_selected_rows = $this.data(key_selected_rows);

        if (true == e.shiftKey) {
            if (rowid != last_selected) {
                var min = parseInt((rowid < last_selected_row ) ? rowid : last_selected_row );
                var max = parseInt((rowid > last_selected_row ) ? rowid : last_selected_row );
                for (var i = min + 1; i < max; i++) {
                    $this.jqGrid(method_setSelection, i, false);
                }
            }
        } else if (false == e.ctrlKey) {
            $this.resetSelection();

            if (!$.string.isNullOrEmpty(url_for_save_edit)) {
                if (!$.isNull(cur_selected_rows) && (cur_selected_rows.length <= 1) && (rowid == last_selected_row)) {
                    var curr_edit_row = $this.data(key_curr_edit_row);
                    console.log('>>>>> curr selected rows = ', cur_selected_rows, ', last selected row = ', last_selected_row, 'curr editing row = ', curr_edit_row, ', to be editable row: ', rowid);
                    if (rowid != curr_edit_row) {
                        if (!$.isNull(curr_edit_row)) {
                            console.log('>>>>> restoring row ', curr_edit_row);
                            $this.jqGrid('restoreRow', curr_edit_row, null);
                        }
                        console.log('>>>>> set row as editable: ', rowid);
                        $this.jqGrid('editRow', rowid, false, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
                        $this.data(key_curr_edit_row, rowid);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you suppose that the rows are **sorted by rowid in asc order** (see `if (true == e.shiftKey)`). I think you should better use `sortname` and `sortorder` parameters of jqGrid. Morover you can use [jQuery.next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) or [jQuery.prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get to the next or previous `<tr>` element.

Moreover I don't understand why you use `$this.data(key_selected_rows)` instead of the standard `this.p.selarrrow`.

Sorry, but I would recommend you **to rewrite** your program and use more DOM properties of `<tr>` (grid row) and `<table>` elements. For example the [rowIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp) property of `<tr>` could gives you the index of the the row in the [rows](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp) collection of the `<table>` element. You can get the next/previous row just using the `this.rows[index+1]` or `this.rows[index+1]` (`this` in the `beforeSelectRow` point to the DOM representation of the `<table>` element).

To your main question: if you want to prevent row selection or unselection in some situation you should return `false` from the `beforeSelectRow`.

Comment: Hi Oleg, since I follow only the jqGrid document, and I'm not familiar with the source code. Further, I'd like to use API rather than accessing the DOM directly. The problem is really strange, once the inserted input box got focused, the originally selected row will be 'de-selected'. Do you have any idea? I've traced up the jqGrid source code on GitHub, but no found.

Comment: @William Choi: Sorry, but you use `this.p.selrow` directly. Why you not use `this.p.selarrrow` and use `$this.data(key_selected_rows)` instead? You use undefined `$.string.isNullOrEmpty`. I suppose that `if (!$.string.isNullOrEmpty(url_for_save_edit))` should be just `if (url_for_save_edit)`. The usage of `this.rows` is exactly so simple as `this.p`, but it corresponds **all standards**, so you can use it much more sure as `this.p`. `this.rows` is not a part of jqGrid, it is a part of DOM standard. jqGrid has no API for existing DOM properties. I will try to test your code and write you more.

Comment: the `$.string.isNullOrEmpty` is a shorthand util method for just simplify my life.

Comment: Since `this.p.selarrrow` will be empty temporarily in some cases, and I need the fact of selected rows.

Comment: @William Choi: The `this.p.selarrrow` is always an array with ids of the selected rows. If no row is selected `this.p.selarrrow` is the empty array (`[]`). At the first call `$this.data(key_selected_rows)` returns `undefined`. If no `editurl` parameter are defined the `$this.data(key_selected_rows)` stay **always** `undefined`. Probably you mean that you set `$this.data(key_selected_rows)` to `[]` somewhere else, but you should at least post more code which you use. The code of all functions which you use (like `$.isNull`) you should also post. Why you need `$.isNull` instead of `=== null`?

Comment: @William Choi: Could you post **the whole demo** which can be used to examine your problem? The demo can use `editurl: 'clientArray'`, `datatype: 'local'` and has at least two rows of data filled in the grid.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I think I found that problem, I modified the following:            } else if (false == e.ctrlKey) {
                var ind = $this.jqGrid('getInd', rowid, true);
                if ("1" != $(ind).attr('editable')){
                    $this.resetSelection();
                }

Comment: i.e. do not perform `resetSelection` if the row is in editing mode.